# Add all Pycharm files to git using keyboard

Tags: git, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to know that, how can I perform `git add -A` equivalent functionality in Pycharm via Keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there isn't such a shortcut in PyCharm. However, there is a workaround for that.

Go to the *Version Control* tab and click `Ctrl-A` to select all the files in *Version Control*, included the not added files as below image:

[image]

Then hit `Ctrl-Alt-A` and all the selected files will be added in the VCS similar to what the `git add -a` does.